# Why doesn't the increment operator change the value of variable in java?

Tags: java

I recently wrote snippet code like this

```
public class TestIncrement {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double a = 12.4; 
        double b = 5.6; 
        a -=b -=b -= b -= b -= b -= b;
        System.out.println(a);
        a-=b; 
        System.out.println(a); 
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
12.4
12.4
```

Why increment operator not work?

Comment: Try printing out the value of b. (And ask your self why is it that value)

Comment: Im somewhat surprised this compiles, it certainly should never be used

Comment: That's a *decrement*.

Answer (score 9):

`-=` and all other assignment operators are right-associative. This line:

```
a -=b -=b -= b -= b -= b -= b;
```

doesn't mean "decrease `a` by the value of `b` 6 times". It means the same as this:

```
a -= (b -= (b -= (b -= (b -= (b -= b)))));
```

which means "decrease `b` by the value of `b`, then decrease `b` by the new value of `b`, then do that 3 more times, then decrease `a` by the final value of `b`". `b` is 0 after the first `-=`, so the rest of the statement does nothing, as does the

```
a-=b;
```

line.

Comment: Or to summarise; if you're going to write an insane program don't be surprised when it does insane things

Answer (score 2):

It does work.  Your `b` variable is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

If I put parentheses around all that to make it easier to understand, we get this:

```
public class TestIncrement {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double a = 12.4; 
        double b = 5.6; 
        a -= (b -= (b -= (b -= (b -= (b -= b)))));
        System.out.println(a);
        a -= b; 
        System.out.println(a); 
    }
}
```

The first `b -= b` statement sets `b` to `0`. After `0` is subtracted from `b` 4 more times, the result is still `0`, which obviously leaves the value of `a` unchanged. Even if you try again, in the `a -= b` line, you will still get the same result: `12.4 − 0.0 = 12.4`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have figured this out on your own, by writing a simpler example.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;

    a -= b -= c;

    System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
}
```

You'd be surprised to see that the output is `2 -1 3` 
This reason is, the above code is equal to:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;

    b -= c;
    a -= b;

    System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
}
```

Don't do spaghetti code. :(